# use different to master branch as release branch on semantic release

Tags: semantic-release

When Im trying to use another release branch for trigger a release with semantic release. Semantic release is telling me

*This test run was triggered on the branch jose, while semantic-release is configured to only publish from master, therefore a new version won’t be published.*`

Is there any way to set up another release branch?

This is my release.config.js file

```
  release: {
    branches: ['jose']
  },
  dryRun: false,
  plugins: [
    "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
    "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
    "@semantic-release/changelog",
    "@semantic-release/github",
    ["@semantic-release/git", {
                "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} \n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
    }],
    ["semantic-release-slack-bot", {
      "notifyOnSuccess": true,
      "notifyOnFail": true,
      "onSuccessTemplate": {
        "text": "A new version of $package_name with version $npm_package_version has been released at $repo_url!"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, in my case the branch exists only locally not on the remote repo. Take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/1587)

Comment: man i really wish the err msg in your terminal just said "did you forget to push to remote?" or something simple

Answer (score 2):

Try to run:

```
npx semantic-release --branches jose
```

Comment: This should be `--branches`, not `--branch`.